# unable to put tab in search and replace in nano editor

Tags: unix, nano

I am trying to search all the space and replace with tab in a file in nano editor. But the file just keeps adding "\t"
When I use search and replace, it won't take in the tab button or ctrl+i. And when I added the quotation sign, it automatically adds literally "\t". Not sure what to do. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be in verbatim mode to get tabs recognized by nano.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458694/find-and-replace-tabs-using-search-and-replace-in-nano.